# Pandas sort_values, duplicate values in sort column

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

How does pandas treat equal values in the column it is sorting by.

dataFrame1

```
a | b | c |
--|---|---|
1 | 2 | 2 |
2 | 1 | 6 |
2 | 1 | 5 |
3 | 4 | 2 |
```

If I run `dataFrame1.sort_values(by=['a'], ascending=True)`

How does it treat the duplicate values in a ?

Comment: treat them the same keep the original order as is

Comment: @BEN_YO I doubt that. the default method is `quicksort` which is not stable.

Comment: True, for duplicate values sometimes it doesn't maintain order. Is there any solution for such abrupt behavior?